# Verify that a glob has a unique expansion in bash (or more generally in posix)

Tags: bash, shell, wildcards

Is there a simple but stable way to verify that a glob pattern has a **unique** expansion in Bash?

```
a=$(echo -n somedir-*); [ -z "$a" ] ...
```

This does only test whether something was expanded or not, and even more depends on the glob settings.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

POSIXly (even Bournely):

```
set -- somedir-[*] somedir-*
case $#-$1-$2 in
  '2-somedir-[*]-somedir-*') echo 0 match;;
  2-*) echo 1 match;;
  *) echo more than one match;;
esac
```

The `somedir-[*]` `somedir-*` is to disambiguate the cases where:

- There is no match (expansion would be `somedir-[*]` `somedir-*`)
- There is one match but it is a literal `somedir-*` (expansion would be `somedir-*` `somedir-*`.

With `bash`, you can do:

```
(shopt -s nullglob
set -- somedir-*
[ "$#" -eq 1 ])
```

`ksh93`, `zsh`, `yash` have a similar feature (the feature comes from `zsh`) but with different syntax.

Comment: If you use the first answer in bash, you must ensure that ``failglob`` and ``nullglob`` are **off** (i.e., unset).